# Inner Join on three tables using Linq

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

How to do inner join on three tables, when one of the tables is using group by. I am able to write this query but it returns error on run time. So how should I modify my query.

```
var pastDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1);

var query = from l in db.picturelikes
            where l.iddatetime > pastDate
            group l by l.idpictures into pgroup
            let count = pgroup.Count()
            orderby count descending
            join p in db.picturedetails on pgroup.FirstOrDefault().idpictures equals p.idpictures
            join u in db.users on pgroup.FirstOrDefault().iduser equals u.iduser
            select new SortedDto
            {
                IdPictures = pgroup.FirstOrDefault().idpictures,
                IdUser = pgroup.FirstOrDefault().iduser,
                totalrating = pgroup.Average(l => (float?)l.likenumber) ?? 0, // pl.Where(a => a.likenumber!= null).Average(c => c.likenumber)
                sex =u.sex,
                username =u.username,
                dob = u.dob 
            };

return query;
```

This is the exception i get with my present code,

> InnerException: { Message: "An error has occurred.", ExceptionMessage:
>   "Unknown column 'Project2.idpictures' in 'where clause'",
>   ExceptionType: "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException", StackTrace: "
>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket() at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow,
>   Int64& insertedId) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32
>   statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int64& insertedId) at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean
>   force) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult() at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) at
>   MySql.Data.Entity.EFMySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDatoiaReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) at
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>   at
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)" }

Is my query legit? Is  it the way to do three inner joins when using groupby.

Comment: Try to use `pgroup.Key` instead of `pgroup.FirstOrDefault().idpictures`

Comment: pgroup.key gives me access to just key of the like not to idpictures and others.

Comment: So i cant join using pgroup.key

Comment: @Hmmmmmmmmmm: Why is this a join on three tables? `p in db.picturedetails` is never used.

Comment: Yeah but later on i need to use table three too i.e db.picturedetails

Comment: To add to the question , even if i dont use where clause i still get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query provider can't handle complex actions for determining the identity of each set for the "join".

Fortunately, you don't need to do something as complex as you are doing.  Rather than using `FirstOrDefault` in the join comparision to get at the field you're grouping on, just use the groups's key:

```
join p in db.picturedetails on pgroup.Key equals p.idpictures
```

You can, and should use `Key` elsewhere in the query as well.

If you want to make it clearer to the reader what they key is, and so want a better variable name, just use a `let`:

```
let detailsId = pgroup.Key
```

And then you can use `detailsId` throughout the query instead.

Since your group needs to also have a constant `userId` value you should also be grouping on that, assuming the groups all currently have the same `userId` value:

```
group l by new{ l.idpictures, l.iduser } into pgroup
```

Then you can access the property of the key that you need in the respective `join` clauses:

```
join p in db.picturedetails on pgroup.Key.idpictures equals p.idpictures
```

---

```
join u in db.users on pgroup.Key.iduser equals u.iduser
```

Comment: This wont work. pgroup.key  will be using idlike to join on p.idpictures from db.picturedetails. Which is not what i want. I want to join both using idpictures.

Comment: @Hmmmmmmmmmm That's the field that you grouped on, so the value of that field is what the `Key` will contain.

Comment: You mean to say key will be containing idpicture?

Comment: Yeah you are right, its working . But how to join the user table?

Comment: join u in db.users on pgroup.Key  equals u.iduser into second this wont join

Comment: Well, the items in that group won't have the same idUser value, so the query inherently won't mean much.  You should group on that as well if you need to access that property.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38350/discussion-between-hmmmmmmmmmm-and-servy)

Comment: i do have iduser property in pictures table, any way to join ??

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
group l by l.idpictures into pgroup
```

to:

```
group l by new { l.idpictures,l.idgroup } into pgroup
```

you will likely have to change your references of `pgroup.FirstOrDefault().idpictures` to `pgroup.idpictures`

alternatively, rework your group so you join first, then group.

Comment: new { l.idpictures,l.idgroup } , i didnt get it? what is l.idgroup

Comment: How can i join first and then group, because i need to my likes to be grouped and become one single like so that they can be joined. Can you clarify?

Comment: Sorry, I meant new {id.idpictures,l.iduser}